# Replicating Table "Promotion" in Databricks w/ S3 Backend

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql, aws-databricks

In my experience with DBMS systems, one safe approach to promoting new datasets for business intelligence is to:

1. Apply updates to a staging table `table_stg`
2. Validate the staging table updates against production table `table_prod`
3. If pass, rename `table_prod` to `table_archive`, rename `table_stg` to `table_prod`
4. Copy `table_prod` as `table_stg`

This is minimally disruptive to end users, in that there are no code changes required and the swap happens quickly as only metadata is updated. It also has the advantage of not having to apply transformation pipelines twice, once to stg, then to prod...

I am trying to design something similar with Databricks delta lake, but have been struggling. First, table renames are blocked without enabling the following:
https://community.wandisco.com/s/article/Apache-Delta-Lake-default-behavior-stops-DELTA-table-renaming

Can I accomplish the same workflow with [table clones](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html) in Delta Lake?

Any insight into the approach that I should take?